# Possible bug in `toc` function in Matlab R2015b

Tags: matlab, time

Usually calling a Matlab function with an empty comma-separated list is the same as calling it without arguments. For example,

```
in={}; spy(in{:});
```

is the same as

```
spy %// call without inputs
```

However, I'm getting strange behviour for the 1-output version of `toc`: this works as expected

```
tic; t=toc
```

whereas this **crashes** (closes Matlab) in R2015b, Windows 7 64 bits:

```
tic; in={}; t=toc(in{:})
```

It works properly in Matlab R2014b, Windows 7 64 bits.

Can someone reproduce this behaviour in R2015b? Any explanation? Possible bug?

Comment: Confirmed for 2015b (8.6.0.267246) on MacOS X.

Comment: Works fine in R2015a on OS X. Crashes R2015b on OS X.

Comment: Thanks both! So it's not OS-related

Comment: Confirmed for R2015b in Windows

Comment: Works fine in R2014b, R2014a, 2015a on Win 7 64 & 32.

Comment: Thank you all. I've filed a bug report at Mathworks

Comment: May I ask how you came across this one?

Comment: @zeeMonkeez I'm finishing a code-golf programming language called MATL (see [Esolang page](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL) and  [Matlab chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/81987/matlab-and-octave)). It allows calling most common Matlab functions. To implement a call with _variable number of input arguments_, say to function `toc`, I gather the inputs in a cell array `in` and then expand into a comma-separated list to do the function call: `toc(in{:})`. So `in={}; toc(in{:})` should be `toc` (but it crashes) , whereas `in={uint64(23435)}; toc(in{:}` is `toc(uint64(23435))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just to close this question*:

From the comments above, this problem happens in **Matlab R2015b** in **various operating systems**. It doesn't happen in older Matlab versions.

I reported a bug to Mathworks. They told me be the developers are aware of this issue and it will be fixed for R2016b.

EDIT (October 3, 2016): I confirm that the bug has been corrected in R2016b.